# How to clear the content of the html input text field using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, textinput

I am having a html text field which can hide.

When hiding I want clear the text field.

I used this and it doesn't work.

`$('#id').val("");`

And I tried `$('#id').text("");` as well.

It removed the whole text field.

Comment: `$('#id').val('');` works. I'm to lazy to make a fiddle, but trust me - it works! `:)`

Comment: Post the code that doesn't work.

Comment: Ah what the heck... here: http://jsfiddle.net/RahKR/1/

Answer (score 8):

This is correct:

```
$('#id').val('');
```

However, your part 2 is interesting.

```
$('#id').text("");
```

That shouldn't create the behavior you're describing.  I expect that you're referencing the parent object, not the `<input>` directly.

Answer (score 2):

What else is happening with your code... because this works for me...

```
<input id="id">
<input id="clear" type="button" value="Clear">
```

and

```
$('#clear').click(function(){
    $('#id').val('');    
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/xrxU8/

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
 $('#id').attr("value","");
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `TheTextField` is the ID of your input field, this works fine.

```
$('#TheTextField').val("");
$('#TheTextField').hide();
```

Anyway, if you are using FireBug and you look at the input field while hidden, you will see that `value` attribute still has a value, which it really doesn't have, but when you show it again:

```
$('#TheTextField').val("");
$('#TheTextField').hide();
$('#TheTextField').show();
```

the input field as you will see it rendered in the browser as opposed to what you are seeing in the FireBug, it has no value anymore.